# C++ HEAP error when delete [] is called

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, delete-operator

I keep getting the error in VS 2100 "CRT detected that the application wrote to memory before start of heap buffer"

Can anyone help? My int Main is all the way on the bottom. The error occur when the `delete []` command is run on the operator= function

```
#include "intset.h"
const int MAXINITIALSIZE = 5;
int IntSet::numOfArray = 0;

IntSet::IntSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    numOfArray++;
    int tempArray[] = {a, b, c, d, e};
    size = determineHighest(tempArray) + 1; //determines largest int
    cout << "size is " << size << endl;

    arrayPtr = new bool[size]; //creates array of bool

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //fill bool array 
    {
        arrayPtr[i]= false;  //arrayptr is a bool pointer created in the header
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXINITIALSIZE; i++)
    {
        arrayPtr[tempArray[i]]= true;
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << &arrayPtr[i] << endl;
    }
}
IntSet::IntSet(const IntSet &intsetObject)
{
    numOfArray++;
    size = intsetObject.size;

    arrayPtr = new bool[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (intsetObject.arrayPtr[i])
            arrayPtr[i] = intsetObject.arrayPtr[i];
    }
}
IntSet::~IntSet()
{
    --numOfArray;
    delete [] arrayPtr;     
    arrayPtr = NULL;
}

int IntSet::determineHighest(int tempArray[])
{
    int temp = tempArray[0];    
    for (int i = 1; i < MAXINITIALSIZE; i++)
    {
        if (tempArray[i] > temp)
            temp = tempArray[i];
        else
            continue;       
    }
    return temp;
}

IntSet& IntSet::operator=(const IntSet &intsetObject) //ask about IntSet&
{
    cout << "inside operator=" << endl;
    if (&intsetObject != this)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << &arrayPtr[i] << endl;
        }
        delete [] arrayPtr;   //HEAP ERROR HERE!
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << &arrayPtr[i] << endl;
        }
        size = intsetObject.size
        arrayPtr = new bool[size]();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (intsetObject.arrayPtr[i])
                arrayPtr[i] = intsetObject.arrayPtr[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream &output, const IntSet &intsetObject)
{
    output << "{ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < intsetObject.size; i++)
    {
        if (intsetObject.arrayPtr[i] == true)
        {
            output << i << " ";
        }
        else 
            continue;
    }
    output << "}";
    return output;
}


//main

#include "intset.h"

int main() {

    IntSet object2(9);   

    IntSet object4(3,6);

    object4 = object2;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your question to a **minimal, self-contained, representative** test case. Nobody wants to sift through a whole real program. Help us help you.

Comment: Also, why do you use plain, old C-arrays instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: Are you sure that line is where the error occurs? Two lines further down seems much more likely.

Comment: You don't have the defaults for a,b,c,d,e set to -1 by any chance, do you?

Comment: And why do you have different code for the copy constructor than for the `operator=`?

Comment: Also, if you're set on using plain old arrays, you might consider using `memcpy` instead of looping over the array, (unnecessarily) testing each element, then copying individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only happen if arrayPtr is accessed with a negative index.  I suspect your defaults for a,b,c,d,e are -1 in the declaration for `IntSet::IntSet`, so it is writing to arrayPtr[-1] in the set-true loop.  Check for `tempArray[i] >= 0` there.

Also, you can't print the array after you have deleted it, so you should remove those lines after the delete, although they should be "harmless" in that only garbage will be printed, but who knows - the OS could release the page containing the array and it could segfault your program.

Finally, you should not test `if (intsetObject.arrayPtr[i])` in the copy & `=` operators.  Otherwise all "false" elements in the source array become uninitialized in the destination array (`new bool[size]` does **not** initialize the array to all `false`).

Comment: thanks guys I do have a header that brings in -1 int for the default constructor. But that will create an array of size [-1 + 1 = 0]. I'm guessing thats not okay in c++?

Comment: thanks guys it was the (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1) parameter in the header file. I fixed it temporarily. Hope this doesnt pop up ever again